# What's the best cheap TV Tuner for Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware, tv

My family are switching from cable to having a HTPC. Im going to buy them a Zotac ITX computer with a 520m in it.  I have found [this cheap tv tuner that I have read works with Linux](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DISGO-FREEVIEW-DIGITAL-TV-TUNER-USB-DONGLE-STICK-RECEIVER-DVB-DVB-T-/250949179221?pt=UK_Computing_Video_Capture_TV_Tuner_Cards&hash=item3a6dbc9755#ht_1454wt_1134)

Will this record on one channel while I record on another?
Is MythTV any good?
Any other good suggestions for a tv stick (It has to be USB as the machine im buying wont have any PCI ports)?

We will be using this HTPC for some 1080p Youtube videos.

Specs:

2GB DDR3 Ram
Nvidia 520m
 500Gb HDD(Big enough for us)
Dual core 2.00 64bit Atom

Answer (score 2):

Any DVB-T tuner will do, as long as you investigate the Linux compatibility before buying. Look into experiences from other Linux users with this device on forums, check the [LinuxTV Wiki](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) for details on the current state of support in the Linux kernel of a wide range of recording devices.

Don't bother for MythTV: it is outdated and bug-ridden. I can highly recommend using [Tvheadend](https://www.lonelycoder.com/tvheadend/), a high-quality and versatile solution meant for recording and watching tv.

Use [XBMC-PVR](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ICvUx5GWOQ) as a front-end to this all. You will get all the usual good that XBMC offers, plus a user-friendly, well-integrated live tv section that you connect with Tvheadend.

Comment: I've used MythTV for many years and have yet to encounter a bug. I looked at the Wiki for TVHeadEnd and within a few minutes found a FAQ which said it doesn't even support pausing live TV (timeshifting) so I leave it up to you to figure out which is the better solution.